# I am searching a JavaHelp still supported alternative

Tags: java, framework

I developed a Java Swing application, and used JavaHelp to generate the help for this one. But JavaHelp is too old and not supported now, I didn't find any alternative (I saw OracleHelp for Java but it's as old as JavaHelp).

Can someone help me ?
N.B : it's not to generate documentation, but help to facilitate the application usage.

Azrix